# Использование std::move для вставки элемента в вектор

Tags: c++, c++11

Пример:

```
class A
{
public:
    A( int _p1, double _p2 )
        : m_p1( _p1 )
        , m_p2( _p2 )
    {}

private:
    int     m_p1;
    double  m_p2;
};
```

Первый случай. Контейнер - вектор, хранящий элементы типа A, тут проблем, кажется нет:

```
std::vector<A> aList;
aList.emplace_back( 10, 12.0 );
```

Мы просто передаем необходимые констуктору класса А параметры в emplace_back - и у нас на месте создается объект.
Как быть в том случае, если вектор хранит элементы типа A*?
Является ли допустимым следующий способ:

```
std::vector<A*> apList;
apList.emplace_back( std::move( new A( 10, 12.0 ) );
```

P.S. Наверное, он был бы корректен в том случае, если бы во втором случае это был не `A*`, а, скажем, `std::unique_ptr<A>` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вектор хранит указатели, move нафиг не нужен, так как копирование указателя - дешевая операция, которая обычно занимает 1 инструкцию процессора.

Answer (score 2):

Все будет работать - просто за отсутствием перемещающего конструктора для указателей будет выполняться обычное копирование указателя, только и всего...